# How to define a property only visible to a method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, scope

I need a variable to describe UISegmentedControl last selected index in view controller. But it is only used in one method.

Can I set the property variable scope within the method only?

Like static variable or closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A property is always scoped at the class level. Though it may be either public or private. Just make it private. There is no need to have a method level property.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK properties cannot be method scoped. 
You could create a private ivar in your @implementation
If you really need or want the convenience of properties and auto synthesis, that private ivar could be an instance of a private class.  But that's overkill probably.

Otherwise you could declare a static variable inside the method itself. 
It wouldn't have visibility outside of the scope of the method.

Comment: The problem with a method static variable is there is only one copy shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: Interesting! I did not know that. So it acts as a pseudo class variable?! Freakshow!!!